# How to inflate a child layout

Tags: java, android, xml, layout-inflater

I'm starting to learn Android Development so this question may sound a bit noobish.
I tried to inflate a child layout inside a parent layout with a template I created, but it throws the error: **The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first**
Here are my codes:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.codingrabbit.spandan.rabbit101.MainActivity">

<include
    layout="@layout/toolbar"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar">
</include>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/contents"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**special_buttons.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/special_button"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Subject"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:background="@color/blue"
    android:id="@+id/subjectText"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="70dp"
    android:text="Details"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:background="@color/green"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/detailsText"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**toolbar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Toolbar Setup:
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("Main Menu");
    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));

    //Adding special buttons:
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.contents);
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        View custom = inflater.inflate(R.layout.special_buttons, parent, true);
        TextView subText = (TextView) custom.findViewById(R.id.subjectText);
        TextView detailsText = (TextView) custom.findViewById(R.id.detailsText);
        subText.setText("Subject: "+(i+1));
        detailsText.setText("Details of subject " + (i + 1));
        parent.addView(custom);    //this is where the error is diplayed
    }
    setContentView(parent);
}
}
```

Comment: Does the application launch/behave correctly if you just remove `parent.addView(custom);`? Specifically, I believe that line may be redundant because the `true` parameter when you call `inflate()` already adds your new child to the parent.

Comment: It worked when I removed both `parent.addView(custom);` and `setContentView(parent);` but then it only creates a single template instead of three like it was programmed to do, that too just the last one i.e. _Subject 3_ @AndrewG

Comment: Why did you remove `setContentView(parent)`?

Comment: It was throwing the same error, but at `setContentView(parent);` this time, so I tried removing that too @AndrewG

Comment: Bearing in mind that I can't see very much of your code to know what layouts you're using and what you aren't, I believe you may want to remove `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` instead of `setContentView(parent)`. Have you defined anything inside the `activity_main.xml` file?

Comment: Those are all my codes, there is nothing missing. Nothing else defined inside the `activity_main.xml` @AndrewG

Comment: Ahh, I had myself confused. You were correct in removing `setContentView(parent)` as it's just as redundant as what you were doing previously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you provide true as third parameter for `inflate`, the inflated view is automatically added to `parent` (the second parameter) and the parent itself is returned. So, in your case you are trying to adding twice the same view to `parent`, which, as the error points out, is not possible.

Change

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.special_buttons, parent, true);
```

with

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.special_buttons, parent, false);
```

and you will get the behaviour you expect

Comment: It throws the same error regardless of changing the `true` to `false`, but it doesn't if I leave it as `true` and remove `parent.addView(custom);` and `setContentView(parent);`. However, it creates only one version of the template, instead of three.

Comment: get rid of `setContentView(parent);`.  *It throws the same error regardless of changing the true to false* What error is throwing then ?

Comment: Okay, I tried setting it to `false`  and removing `setContentView(parent)` only, it created the template, but this time only the first one, i.e. _Subject 1_ and not the other 3

Comment: in special_buttons.xml change `android:layout_height="match_parent"` to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Answer (score 0):

inflater.inflate(R.layout.special_buttons, parent, false);